# c# convert string 4,60E+12 to int / int64

Tags: c#, string, int

I have list string
 - "1,60E+12" 
 - "2,60E+12"
 - "3,60E+12"
 - "8,60E+12"
How convert this string  to int / int64 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, you just need to use the `<type>.Parse` overload which [specifies the number styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c09yxbyt(v=vs.110).aspx) to allow the exponent:

```
int number = Int32.Parse(value, NumberStyles.AllowExponent);
```

And for a list of strings:

```
var numbers = values.Select(x => int.Parse(x, NumberStyles.AllowExponent)).ToList();
```

If your numbers have decimal points (*also see the footnote for a shorter style*), you'll need:

```
Int32.Parse(value, NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```

And, as your numbers appear to use a culture specific format (using `,` for a decimal point) you may also need to specify a format provider like so:

```
Int32.Parse(value, 
    NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE").NumberFormat);
```

If your numbers are too large then you'll need to use long instead of int otherwise you'll get an `OverflowException`.

*There is no difference between the output from `Int32.Parse` and `int.Parse`. Stylistically I prefer the latter.*

---

**Footnote:** You can get all the combined styles required to do a full exponent parse by simply specifying `NumberStyles.Float`. As per [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) this style ... indicates

> that the AllowLeadingWhite, AllowTrailingWhite, AllowLeadingSign, AllowDecimalPoint, and AllowExponent styles are used. This is a composite number style.

Comment: Also using an integral type (`int` or `long`) causes an error at runtime, at least on Mono ([demo](http://ideone.com/b0sSfs)). If you use `decimal` instead, everything works.

Comment: I believe you will only see that on Mono, in which case you'll need `(long)(decimal.Parse...)`. I don't know why that happens on Mono, though.

Comment: In fact, if I have scanned the commit correctly, it looks like this has been fixed in mono as per [6a517338](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/6a517338122f0df19bc264dd01a5a82521c2d8a5). See `Int64Test` line 335 `Assert.AreEqual (32500000, long.Parse ("32.5E6", NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowExponent), "A#9");`